# IntelliJ Ultimate, Project shows only a few files and does not recognize php

Tags: php, symfony, intellij-idea

I am imported my Project trough git, the project is a php project running on symfoy2.
However it seems that intelliJ does not recognize it as a php project and therefore only shows a bunch of files (static web files such as .js, images, ... )

I was wondering if there is a fix for this, i did the following already:
- Installed php, symfony2 modules
- I am running IntelliJ Ultimate

Comment: are the .php files shown as text file (no highlighting, etc.) or not shown at all? Were any modules created when importing a project? Please check the Project Structure/project Settings/Modules - what do you see there?

Comment: You should use PHPStorm, http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ base on intelliJ

Comment: @lena i see only the folders with static assets in it. Benjamin, i know its possible in the ultimate version, i am running it on my home computer where it works perfectly.

Comment: what modules do you have in your project? See my previous comment

Comment: Fixed indeed, i had to add web module to project structure

Comment: That's worth writing as an answer @MaximGeerinck

Comment: added it, sorry i am relatively new to stackoverflow, thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the existing modules (in project structure settings) and added the web module, that fixed my issue